# Refresh session time when user confirm's to stay online

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I am working on JSF framework. In Web.xml session time out time is 5 min. After 4 min i am showing confirm dialog for the user whether to stay active or not. After clicking on Yes I tried sessionObject.setMaxInactiveInterval(5). But session gets invalidated after 5th min. Is there a way to extend user session time dynamically without changing time in web.xml.

```
public void refreshSession(){
        //code to refresh the session
        System.out.println("want to stay alive");
        HttpSession currentSession = ServerUtility.getSession();
        currentSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(2*60);
    }
```

Comment: are you hitting the right method if user want to continue the session , please share the code for precise answer

Answer (score 2):

Web.xml sets timeout setting is global, it's applicable for the whole application.
But  if you want to extend the session time, you need to create method containing following code:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(5*60);
```

What you can do is create an endpoint which executes above-mentioned code

```
public void extendSession(){
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(5*60);
}
```

If User doesn't want to continue then below code will end session immediately:

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(0); // inactive immediately
```

Comment: this did not help. still getting logged out after 5th min.

Comment: tomcat @mohitsharma

Comment: @ShreekrishnaBellubbi I guess there is something else which is interfering the timeout.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848327/httpsession-setmaxinactiveinterval-not-working-in-tomcat-6